# Create a ListView in VB.NET that is similar to the jQuery datatable

Tags: jquery, vb.net, listview, datatables, listviewitem

I am currently working on a ListView in VB.NET 2015 that retrieves data from my database then populates it with the query result. I think that I can manage through my data more efficient if its displayed dynamically and more flexible than it already is if its functional as the jQuery datatables feature used on the HTML platform (ex. paging, ordering, info, etc.).

How can I create something similar to that using VB.NET 2015?

This image link is https://datatables.net/ example of their datatables, which I am aiming to create:

[image]

Comment: As an aside: The JQuery datatable doesn't natively support filtering at source. That means your page gets the full record set and jQuery applies a filter to the results. This can get slow depending on the number fo records...when looking for a solution it might be something to consider..

Comment: I see. Doing the same kind of filtering to VB.NET ListView control would need a set of buttons, labels, and query statements. Then I've found out that using VB.NET DataGridView control instead of ListView is a better option to what I am aiming for because of its database-specific properties.